# Adding column values as long as a value in other column matches

Tags: python, python-2.7, summarize

How do I add column values as long as a value in the other column is the same?

e.g. from the following list:

```
Time   Value
10       a
20       b
10       c
10       d
20       f
```

I want to obtain the following result:

```
Time      Value
10       (a+c+d)
20        (b+f)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is this a `dataframe`?

Comment: What is this indeed? How does your data look like in python?

Comment: Joe Iddon , Anton vBR am importing from a text file. I have seven columns of string data, I need 5 columns to group by being summed according to Time occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), then select the `Value` elements (so you don't `sum` the `Times`), then finally [**`apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `sum`.

```
>>> d = {'Time': [10,20,10,10,20], 'Value': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   Time Value
0    10     a
1    20     b
2    10     c
3    10     d
4    20     f
>>> df.groupby(['Time'])['Value'].apply(sum).reset_index()
   Time Value
0    10   acd
1    20    bf
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pandas solution if you have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data ='''\
Time   Value
10       a
20       b
10       c
10       d
20       f'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

newdf = df.groupby('Time')['Value']\
        .apply(lambda x: '({})'.format('+'.join(x)))\
        .reset_index()

print(newdf)
```

Returns:

```
   Time    Value
0    10  (a+c+d)
1    20    (b+f)
```

Comment: I need the sum of a,c and d not a concatenation

Comment: @MusaNdiaye In that case it is `newdf = df.groupby('Time')['Value'].apply(sum).reset_index()`. This however smells like a dupe, a pretty basic operation. Joe Iddon has the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
L = [10, 'a', 20, 'b', 10, 'c', 10, 'd', 20, 'f']
x = 0
while x < len(L):
  dd[L[x]].append(L[x+1]);
  x = x+ 2

for key, val in dd.iteritems():
  print key, reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, val)

print dd
```

Comment: what is **L** ? we never have something like this in real programs

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    'a': 10,
    'b': 20,
    'c': 10,
    'd': 10,
    'f': 20
}

v = {}

for key, value in sorted(data.iteritems()):
    v.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

print v
```

And the resault :

```
{10: ['a', 'c', 'd'], 20: ['b', 'f']}
```